# How to programatically change the total_rows in the pagination config file

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Im wondering if it is possible to change the total_rows **dynamically in the pagination config** file as the total_rows may be not be the same for all the queries. Here is my code:

```
$config['base_url'] = current_url();
$config['total_rows'] = 200; //I need to change dynamically
$config['per_page'] = 20;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-small pagination-centered">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['first_link'] = '';
$config['last_link'] = '';
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the only way would be to redeclare your config settings in your controller for the specific cases when it isn't 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
$count = $this->db->count_all_results( 'table_name' );

$total_rows = 4;
  if ( $count > $total_rows ) {
    $config['base_url'] = current_url();
    $config['total_rows'] = $count; //I need to change dynamically
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-small pagination-centered">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
    $config['first_link'] = '';
    $config['last_link'] = '';  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but is that possible to make it more flexible. I mean I am using PDO and the number of row I might need might not always be the total number of row in a particular table. An example would be, select * name from students where name like '%Lea%'. Thanks

Comment: But why do you whant to change the total_rows dynamically.
I mean, the per_page already limits how many rows will be displayed.
Sorry, but i just try to understaind why do you need this.